# SPARQL regexp with variables

Tags: regex, rdf, sparql

I am trying to perform a relative simple regex query, however it uses a variable inside the regexp. Is sparql not capable of using these kind of concatenation or am I using a wrong method? What I am trying to query is the following:

```
SELECT *
 WHERE {
    ?part local:part_start ?start .
    ?chunk local:long_region ?long_region   
    BIND(REPLACE(?long_region, ".{"+?start+"}(.{10}).*", "$1") AS ?regionX)
}
```

I will end up with a small part from a long region of characters according to a start location and 10 characters further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `+` cannot be used for string concatenation in most SPARQL implementations, in principal an implementation can support this as an [extended operator mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#operatorExtensibility) but I'm not aware of any that do.

Instead you can use the standard [`CONCAT()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-concat) function to achieve your aim provided you are using a [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) compliant engine:

```
SELECT *
 WHERE {
    ?part local:part_start ?start .
    ?chunk local:long_region ?long_region   
    BIND(REPLACE(?long_region, CONCAT(".{", ?start, "}(.{10}).*"), "$1") AS ?regionX)
}
```

Comment: Jena supports + as string concatenation.
But if ?start is number, string+number is undefined.  It would need str(?start).